# Having problem with twitterR, language cannot be defined

Tags: r, database, twitter, twitter-r

I have been reviewing an online R class. The data Science and machine learning with R, I am doing the natural language processing part.

I was following the code as follows:

```
library(twitteR) 
library(tm) 
library(wordcloud) 
library(RColorBrewer)

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) 
[1] "Using direct authentication"

searchTwitteR("soccer", n=1000, lang = "en")
```

However, the language can not be defined. I got an error as :
**Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘language’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “NULL”)**

Anyone can help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend using the rtweet package instead.

Comment: Thank you. But it will be a different story than this lecture.